# have /home/user/Downloads (and other user folders) on a different partition

Tags: directory, home, ecryptfs

I recently got an SSD. I use it to store my `/` as well as my `/home` directories (on different partitions).

For each user, I would like to have most of their folders on my big RAID-1 with 2 hard drives (I'm talking about `/home/<user>/Downloads`, `/home/<user>/Music`, `/home/<user>/Documents`, etc. to make this more clear).

First I thought about symlinks, but I think this wouldn't work, as the whole home-directories should be encrypted with [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/).

So, how can this be achieved?

Comment: See [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7429/discussion-between-marcel-and-jasonwryan) about closing as a duplicate

Comment: IMHO, it will be easier to have `/home` in the Raid 1 drive, but in a separate partition.

Comment: The other post has an accepted answer that doesn't seem to address this problem, so I guess we'll leave it separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Yet it is not perfect, but I think it can be improved.
Basically I did what @rcoup suggested here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/103835/securely-automount-encrypted-drive-at-user-login/165451#165451

On debian for some reason `mount.ecryptfs_private` is in `/sbin/`. One can access `mount.ecryptfs_private` without root-privileges, however instead of

```
mount.ecryptfs_private extra
```

I had to use

```
/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private extra
```

I wrote a script to mount every folder in `home` seperately, however that's maybe not the best way to do it, as everytime I move a file (e.g. from `Downloads` to `Music`) this process takes some time. Maybe it would be better to use `/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private` to just mount one folder and use symlinks then.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an encrypted partition on the RAID, and give each user a directory there (just like `/home/user` with respect to user/group ownership), and symlink the offending directories in there. I don't know offhand if such a setup will work with all users of those directories, or if there is a way to make the `user`'s `Downloads` just really be at `/home2/user/Downloads` by some overall or user-specific configuration.